# Swagger and .Net Core 3 integration

Tags: swagger, .net-core-3.0

I'm documenting my web api using swagger. However when I run my Project, it throws an error "Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware...".

I only followed the tutorials from youtube. Not sure what is the cause of error.

My project is .Net Core 3.

```
 internal class SwaggerConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info() { Title = "Sample Portal API", Version = "1.0.0.0" });
        });
    }

    public static void Configure(IConfiguration configuration, IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var swaggerOptions = new SwaggerOptions(configuration).Bind();

        app.UseSwagger(options =>
        {
            options.RouteTemplate = swaggerOptions.Route;
        });


        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint(swaggerOptions.UIEndpoint, swaggerOptions.Description);
        });
    }
    private class SwaggerOptions
    {
        IConfiguration _configuration;
        public SwaggerOptions(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public string Route { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string UIEndpoint { get; set; }

        public SwaggerOptions Bind()
        {
            _configuration.GetSection(nameof(SwaggerOptions)).Bind(this);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        SwaggerConfiguration.Configure(services);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        SwaggerConfiguration.Configure(Configuration, app);

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

    }
```

Can someone shed a light, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get it going by following this link (*updated 8/20/2019 as of this writing*):

[Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Take a look at their GitHub link too:

[AspNetCore.Docs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger/samples/)

Comment: great thanks! it works! so swagger for .Net Core 3 is still on prebuild.

Answer (score 12):

Here is the least amount of step in order to add the swagger to your project.

1. Run below command at PowerShell

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -Version 5.5.1
```

2. In the Startup class, add this reference
   '''
   using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
   '''
3. Add below to ConfigureService method in the startup class:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    });
```

4. Add below to the Configure method in the startup.cs

```
// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwagger();

    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
    // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    })
```

5. You can access the swagger page at http://localhost:port/swagger

Comment: better than the accepted one which is just a link only answer

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and all I needed to do is to update Nuget Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to version 5.4.1 or install it if you don't have it.