# System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware..ctor

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am updating my .NET application from .NET v2.1 to v3.1. I am encountering this error which says:

> Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware..ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegate, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.StaticFileOptions>, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)'.
> "

This is the stack trace:

```
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.CreateStaticFileMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, SwaggerUIOptions options)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware..ctor(RequestDelegate next, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, SwaggerUIOptions options)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at RightPartApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\SoleraCodes\RightGlass\RightPartAPI\rightpartapi\src\RightPartApi\Program.cs:line 48\
```

This is the screenshot of the exception:

[image: Exception Screenshot]

Some of the suggestion say I should not update Swashbuckle but I saw PackageReference file. The Swashbuckle is in v4.0.1 but I am getting this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58142734/swagger-and-net-core-3-integration

Does this helps?

Comment: @neerruganti jagadeesh, Did you update the relevant Nuget packages as well while upgrading to 3.1. Seems like you are still using old Nuget package that might be missing the constructor called at runtime. Trying upgrading all the Nuget packages to the version supported for v3.1